# Maintenance plan using external tool to execute query and stored procedures giving off no results

Tags: stored-procedures, database-tuning, performance, performance-tuning

My situation is as follows:
I am using a third party tool (VisualCron) to run stored procedures and sql queries on several database servers.
The stored procedures are from http://ola.hallengren.com/ and the sql queries are as follows:

Sql query to check index fragmentation.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
    FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[sysobjects] 
    WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[tempdb].[dbo].[tmp_indexfragmentation_details]'))
    DROP TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[tmp_indexfragmentation_details] 

CREATE TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[tmp_indexfragmentation_details](
    [DatabaseName]                  [nvarchar] (1000) NULL,
    [ObjectName]                    [nvarchar] (1000) NULL,
    [Pagecount]                         INT,
    [indexName]                     [nvarchar] (1000) NULL,
    [avg_fragmentation_percent]     float NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
DECLARE @dbname varchar(1000)
DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE dbcursor CURSOR for
SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')and  state not in('6')
OPEN dbcursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @dbname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sqlQuery = '
    USE [' + @dbname + '];

    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT compatibility_level 
        FROM sys.databases 
        WHERE 
            name  = N'''+ @dbname +'''
            AND compatibility_level >= 90
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [tempdb].[dbo].[tmp_indexfragmentation_details] 
        (
            DatabaseName
            , ObjectName
            , IndexName
            , avg_fragmentation_percent
            , PageCount
        ) 
            SELECT db_name() as DatabaseName,
dbtables.[name], 
dbindexes.[name],
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
    END;'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery
FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor
INTO @dbname
END
CLOSE dbcursor
Deallocate dbcursor
-- Show the index fragmentation result
SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[tmp_indexfragmentation_details] 
ORDER BY databasename, avg_fragmentation_percent desc
```

Sql query to check database size (for baseline)

```
with Temp
as (select database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 / 1024 size from sys.master_files)
select (select sum(CAST(size AS DECIMAL (38, 2))) from Temp where  Temp.database_id = db.database_id) DataFileSizeGB, Name
from sys.databases db 
order by datafilesizeGB desc
```

After these 2 queries save their results in an .xlsx file, I run the following stored procedure using the basic script as found on http://ola.hallengren.com/ .

```
execute dbo.indexoptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES, -%WSSContent%, -%SP2013%, -%WSS_CONTENT%',
@fragmentationmedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE',
@fragmentationLevel2 = '30',
@fragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = '5',
@fragmentationLow = 'NULL'

execute dbo.indexoptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES, -%WSSContent%, -%SP2013%, -%WSS_CONTENT%',
@updatestatistics = 'all',
@FragmentationLevel1 = '5',
@FragmentationLevel2 = '30'
```

- When I run the stored procedure in SSMS, followed by the query to check fragmentation I can see changes in the indexes
- When I run the stored procedure using my third party tool, I don't see any changes in the indexes
- The stored procedure takes the same amount of time using the third party tool, as it does running directly in SSMS
- When I check sql profiler, I can see the stored procedure being executed when being run from VisualCron

How do I go about further troubleshooting the stored procedure being run from VisualCron?

Answer (score 3):

By default IndexOptimize is skipping indexes with less than 1000 pages. You can read more about this in the [Frequently Asked Questions](http://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html). Could this explain it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Unfortunately I found that the VisualCron client was not correctly transferring the parameters of the stored procedure, so I decided to do without the added step of using VisualCron. So it was unrelated to your awesome script.